# Can a synchronized static method cause a class level lock?

Tags: java, static

If a class A is having a public static method which is tagged by 'synchronized' keyword, then Is there a possibility to have class level lock?

When there is a lock in such class, Can We instantiate object of that class or it has nothing to do with instantiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a class A is having a public static method which is tagged by
>   'synchronized' keyword, then Is there a possibility to have class
>   level lock?

Yes, there would be a class level lock on class A.

> When there is a lock in such class, Can We instantiate object of that class or it has nothing to do with instantiation?

When there is a lock on a static method, it only affects other *synchronized* static methods. You can still create a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the lock will be maintained on the Class object.

Quoted from [Locks In Synchronized Methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

All the other threads trying to execute another static synchronized method of the same class, or any other method synchronized on this `Class` instance will be blocked.